# binding some label dynamically according to the object

Tags: java, swing

I have a javaclass extending FrameView,in this I place some labels,I want to load these labels dynamically(with some images texts and some other etc).
More specifically i want to bind these labels with an object of a classes dynamically.
That is for example when loading the visual class I want to place object of Mail class to first label, and load Sms class to next label ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Metawidget](http://metawidget.sourceforge.net/) to generate GUI base on object.